# How to create OpenVPN on a DG834G v3 router?

Tags: router, vpn, openvpn

Could anyone help me to set up a VPN to my home lan which is handled by a Netgear DG834G v3 router? I know it's a little bit old router, so I hope it is possible.

The NETGEAR manual refers to custom software "*NETGEAR ProSafeVPN Client*" but I want to use OpenVPN or similar.

If not could you suggest me a new mid-high end router with this capabilities? (I found Asus RT-AC68U or Netgear R7000 Nighthawk)

Comment: Have you read the manual yet? The manual for your router can be found [here](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/DG834GV3/DG834Gv3_RM_20JAN06.pdf).

Comment: Yep, but it refers to a custom software NETGEAR ProSafeVPN Client. I want to use OpenVPN or similar if possible (I missing to explain, I'll add now into original post :) )

Comment: It seems the router may support a custom firmware such as OpenWRT which should have an OpenVPN server capability. If you don't want to flash the ROM then you'll need an OpenVPN server behind your router and port forward to the VPN server.